# Grails test plugins not loaded in custom environment when running test-app

Tags: grails

When using a custom environment (`testjenkins`) for our ci server the build-test-data plugin is not loaded for integration tests. In the `BuildConfig.groovy` we have the following:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  ...
  plugins {
    ...
    test ':build-test-data:2.2.3'
    ...
  }
}
```

It seems like the plugin is only loaded when running `test-app` with the default `test` environment. This is not a problem of the plugin because it's the same with other plugins specified as a `test` dependency.

The Grails versions **2.1.3** and **2.4.4** do have this problem. I have not tested other versions.

So the question is: How can Grails be told to load `test` dependencies for a custom environment when running `test-app`?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I have found is to add the plugins as a `test` and a `provided` dependency:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  ...
  plugins {
    ...
    test ':build-test-data:2.2.3'
    provided ':build-test-data:2.2.3'
    ...
  }
}
```